# MATLAB: Is there a callback function for impoint when the dragging stops?

Tags: matlab, mouse

I'm trying to create a plot with draggable points (using [impoly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impoly.html)) in MATLAB GUI.

The mostly used **addNewPositionCallback** function got executed whenever the point is moving.

I would like to trigger another function once I stop dragging the point, because it's an intense computation that I don't want to execute whenever the point moves.

I tried methods like using **WindowButtonUpFcn**, but the problem is, impoint has a stopDrag() function where the **WindowButtonUpFcn** is cleared when dragging stops...

```
function stopDrag(varargin)
    dragMotion();

    iptremovecallback(h_fig, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', ...
        drag_motion_callback_id);
    iptremovecallback(h_fig, 'WindowButtonUpFcn', ...
        drag_up_callback_id);

    % enable the figures pointer manager.
    iptPointerManager(h_fig, 'enable');
end % stopDrag
```

Please help suggest some ways to get around with this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about this (it's just an idea though I haven't tested it with an application like yours but it might be worth a try):

1) In your GUI, if you add a addNewPositionCallback like this:

```
SomeVariable = addNewPositionCallback(hPoint,@GetPointPosition);
```

where hPoint is the handle to the moving point, @GetPointPosition is an anonymous function that you call which gets the current point position:

```
PointPosition(someIndex) = getPosition(hPoint) % store positions in an array
```

then you could compare consecutive entries of PointPosition and if two consecutive positions are identical, then the point has stopped moving and you can call your function of interest.

As I said above that's just an idea; I used a similar code for detecting a dragged rectangle (i.e. imrect instead of impoint) in a GUI and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you. But this is not working well for 2 reasons:  (1) when near boundaries, it's easy to get into situations where the mouse is still dragging but the point position doesn't change so causing false callback... (2) more importantly, when you stop dragging, the point array simply records the last position of the point, no consecutive positions are identical thus event not detected...

Comment: I cannot imagine that there is no easy callback function that allows you to detect when the stop dragging event happens...

Comment: oh shoot sorry then. Yep that's odd that such a callback does not exist

Comment: I ended up using WindowButtonUpFcn ... the event is triggered whenever the mouse button is released... this compromise is of course not ideal but at least it works when I'm in control..